# What is "c/s" in context of hash cracking?

Tags: hash

I was reading hashcat's About page, and the stats are listed in terms of c/s....is that "Cracks per seconds"....the 'c' part seems wrong, I'm just guessing. What is 'c'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"c/s is "crypts" (password hash or cipher computations) per second"

Quoted from the John the Ripper FAQ: http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml

Comment: So technically it means the same basic thing as your guess if you think about it...

Comment: I think we all agree on what's measured, but do you have a source for "crypts"?  Seems equally likely that they intend c as an abbreviation for (hash) calculations per second.  Crypts seems like the wrong terminology for hashing (unless its something like bcrypt where the hash is built from a cipher).

Comment: Added in edit the source above.

Comment: @drjimbob: The Unix password hashing function is named `crypt()`, because in early implementations it actually used the DES cipher.  For compatibility, they didn't change the name when they changed the algorithm.